# Athena - String to Date coversion

Tags: amazon-athena

I want to convert below string to only date column. the column has both time and date stored as string

**String**
2021-01-01 12:43:58  ==> 2021-01-01

Answer (score 0):

You achieve what you want with this query:

```
SELECT
cast(date_parse(column, '%Y-%m-%d') as date)
FROM
table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_format` with `date_parse` or cast as date to achieve this:

```
SELECT date_format(date_parse('2021-01-01 12:43:58', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

will give `2021-01-01`

Just replace the timestamp with column name

```
SELECT date_format(date_parse(<timestamp_column>, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now using cast as shown below

SELECT cast(date_parse('2021-01-01 12:43:58', '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') as date)

similarly replace timestamp with column name

Answer (score 0):

For what is worth, here's a solution without casting back and forth from string to date:

```
select substr(column,1,10) from mytable
```